# When consuming a WCF service, is it good form to return from within a using statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, using

I have a WCF service that I am consuming, and have been doing well so far.

However on our production system with a lot of traffic, I am noticing that that after gradual consistent rise and falls in memory (time in between gradually elongates and the delta gradually increases), the memory consumption is trending higher.

I'm wondering if it could be due to the way I am consuming the DAL web service:

For example:

```
    public static int GetUserTypeFromProfileID(int profileID)
    {
        try
        {
            memberServiceClient = new MemberServiceClient();                                // connect to the data service
            return memberServiceClient.GetUserTypeFromProfileID(profileID);                 // get the profileID associated with the sessionID
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging.Instance.Fatal(ex);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

If I changed this to the following, using a `using` statement:

```
    public static int GetProfileIDFromSessionID(string sessionID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (memberServiceClient = new MemberServiceClient())                                // connect to the data service
            {
                return memberServiceClient.GetProfileIDFromSessionID(sessionID);                // get the profileID associated with the sessionID
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging.Instance.Fatal(ex);
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Is it good form to perform the return inside the `using` section?

Comment: Implementing `IDisposable` is generally done for a reason.

Comment: I agree that `using (...)` should be used if possible, for the type is probably `IDisposable` for a reason. But where is the `memberServiceClient` field (or property) used otherwise? Could it be a local variable of this method instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is nothing specific to WCF with using statement. It will dispose your MemberServiceClient before returning the value.

However Dispose() method on a WCF service client calls [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195520) method inside, which can throw exceptions. So it's better to call Close() method directly. You should also call [Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.icommunicationobject.abort) method when exceptions occur. Here's the recommended implementation.

```
var result;
try
{
    memberServiceClient = new MemberServiceClient();
    result = memberServiceClient.GetUserTypeFromProfileID(profileID);
    memberServiceClient.Close();
}
catch (FaultException e)
{
    //handle exception
    memberServiceClient.Abort();
}
catch (CommunicationException e)
{
    //handle exception
    memberServiceClient.Abort();
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    //handle exception
    memberServiceClient.Abort();
}
```

*Note: I have written a simple base class that handles these details. It's on [NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/WcfClientBase).*

**Update:**

Here's an example with WcfClientBase as requested:

```
public class MemberServiceManager : ServiceClientBase<MemberServiceClient>
{
    public int GetUserTypeFromProfileID(int profileID)
    {
        //makes a call to GetUserTypeFromProfileID operation, closes the channel and handles the exceptions
        //you may want to implement another base class for overriding exception handling methods
        //return value will be default of return type if any exceptions occur
        return PerformServiceOperation(item => item.GetUserTypeFromProfileID(profileID));
    }

    //or you can manually check if any exceptions occured with this overload
    public bool TryGetUserTypeFromProfileID(int profileID, out int userType)
    {
        return TryPerformServiceOperation(item => item.GetUserTypeFromProfileID(profileID), out userType);
    }


    //these exception handling methods should be overriden in another common subclass
    //they re-throw exceptions by default
    protected override void HandleCommunicationException(CommunicationException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }

    protected override void HandleFaultException(FaultException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }

    protected override void HandleTimeoutException(TimeoutException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
    }

}
```

You can also take a look at the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ufukh/WcfClientBase/blob/master/WcfClientBase/ServiceClientBase.cs)

Comment: This answer also properly deals with calling `Abort` on error cases rather than on checking the client's `State` property (as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/11215651/64348 in Dylan's answer). Checking `State` (whether in a `using` or not) is a race condition.

Comment: `Close` is effectively called twice by having the Dispose outside of the `try\catch` block. Once in the `Abort` and once in the `Dispose`.

Comment: @Dylan I have updated the order. FaultException should be in the first order.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - In the case where you have several service methods that you're calling, this syntax will get a bit lengthy.  In that case, what about passing the method to invoke on the service as a method parameter (reflection I guess)... but that would slow things down.  So this is a case of verbose vs. short-hand? I'm guessing that's what you have in your NuGet package?

Comment: @ElHaix Yep, you can pass a lambda expression for your service method.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - can you give some examples of implementation using your WcfClientBase in the context of memberServiceClient?

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları - Thank you for the example, however still some questions.  Please take a look at this new related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435245/how-to-use-the-wcfclientbase-helper-class-for-wcf-connections