# How to use the WcfClientBase helper class for WCF connections?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-client

[Ufuk Hacıoğulları](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205859/ufuk-haciogullari) wrote a nice WCF helper class called [WcfClientBase](https://github.com/ufukh/WcfClientBase).  However I've had some difficulty in implementing it.

I defined my class as follows:

```
public class ModelsBaseClass : ServiceClientBase<MemberServiceClient>
{...
```

And attempting to use the helper class in the following method that returns a complex object through Entity Framework:

```
    public static MyProject.DAL.Primary.Models.sq_newsfeed_GetProfileByID_Result GetAllProfileDetails(int profileID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (memberServiceClient = new MemberServiceClient())                                // connect to the data service
            {
                return memberServiceClient.GetAllProfileDetailsByID(profileID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorLogging.Instance.Fatal(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Following the examples [here](https://gist.github.com/3086253), I am unable to access the class' methods even though this is a derived class, and the `protected` access modifier should allow access - right?

Basically I cannot access the `PerformServiceOperation` or `TryPerformServiceOperation` methods in my model base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice your method is `static`? That's the reason you cannot access instance members of the parent class.